# Conversion deadlock caused by stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, locking, deadlock

We've got a problem with conversion deadlocking going on within one environment (the same proc + trigger works in at least four other environments).

The stored procedure in question inserts a row into a table (cmsreceipt) that has a trigger which updates another table (cmsreceiptarchive). To try and prevent deadlocks a select on the cmsreceiptarchive table with xlock, rowlock is done before the insert to get a lock on the table that the trigger updates. This works in four versions of the db but not in this one environment (sql 2005).

I'll copy the deadlock graph below but to me it seems as though we're getting table scans that are taking to long to complete on table CmsReceipt and this allows another SPID running the same proc to get a shared lock on the table too and then they both try and get IX locks once they're ready to do the update on CmsReceipt.

I've checked the indexes (a clustered index and two non-clustered) and they match the other databases that work fine so I don't know why we're getting table scans on this db but not in the others.

I've tried all sorts of hints (both in the main process and the trigger) but to no avail.

Help! Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process76d5708">
  <process-list>
<process id="process76d5708" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 7:1550628567:0 " waittime="4776" ownerId="34034594" transactionguid="0x4e9e61bf45eed2429a05ad44fa09ec50" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2009-11-24T15:51:12.280" XDES="0x1e0ca5970" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="8" kpid="14340" status="suspended" spid="57" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="3" lastbatchstarted="2009-11-24T15:51:17.513" lastbatchcompleted="2009-11-24T15:49:54.807" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="XXX" hostpid="4804" loginname="XXXX" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="34034594" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
<executionStack>
<frame procname="XXX.dbo.Main_InsertCmsReceipt" line="43" stmtstart="2388" stmtend="3096" sqlhandle="0x03000700d7b7b271d2daf900cb9c00000100000000000000">
insert into CmsReceipt with (updlock)  (
 CmsReceiptId,
 ModifiedAt,
 ModifiedBy,
 CmsMessageId,
 Status,
 Details,
 ReceiptTimestamp,
 SenderName,
 SenderId
    )
    values (
 @New_CmsReceiptId,
 @New_ModifiedAt,
 @New_ModifiedBy,
 @New_CmsMessageId,
 @New_Status,
 @New_Details,
 @New_ReceiptTimestamp,
 @New_SenderName,
 @New_SenderId
)     </frame>
</executionStack>
<inputbuf>

Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1907537879]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process70a1dc8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 7:1550628567:0 " waittime="4498" ownerId="34034604" transactionguid="0x6719e8b21f633a48bf47c77a62f2af2c" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2009-11-24T15:51:12.483" XDES="0x1e1a77970" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="6" kpid="13632" status="suspended" spid="69" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="3" lastbatchstarted="2009-11-24T15:51:17.780" lastbatchcompleted="2009-11-24T15:49:54.807" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="XXXX" hostpid="4804" loginname="XXXXXX" isolationlevel="serializable (4)" xactid="34034604" currentdb="1" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673185824" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="XXX.dbo.Main_InsertCmsReceipt" line="43" stmtstart="2388" stmtend="3096" sqlhandle="0x03000700d7b7b271d2daf900cb9c00000100000000000000">
insert into CmsReceipt with (updlock)  (
CmsReceiptId,
 ModifiedAt,
 ModifiedBy,
 CmsMessageId,
 Status,
 Details,
 ReceiptTimestamp,
 SenderName,
 SenderId
    )
    values (
 @New_CmsReceiptId,
 @New_ModifiedAt,
 @New_ModifiedBy,
 @New_CmsMessageId,
 @New_Status,
 @New_Details,
 @New_ReceiptTimestamp,
 @New_SenderName,
 @New_SenderId
)     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 7 Object Id = 1907537879]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1550628567" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="XXX.dbo.CmsReceipt" id="lock9c4eec80" mode="S" associatedObjectId="1550628567">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process70a1dc8" mode="S"/>
    </owner-list>
<waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process76d5708" mode="IX" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1550628567" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="XXX.dbo.CmsReceipt" id="lock9c4eec80" mode="S" associatedObjectId="1550628567">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process76d5708" mode="S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process70a1dc8" mode="IX" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
```

PS Is there an easier way than 4 spaces at the start of each line to get the xml to show?

Comment: If you select the XML text and click the code button (010101) the editor will add the spaces for you.

Comment: Can you paste the code fragment / stored procedure code for the dbo.Main_InsertCmsReceipt procedure as well?

Comment: Still need help if anyone has any ideas please?

Comment: I added more info to my answer discussing your new information, see the edited section below...

Comment: I assume you figured this out, or came to a resolution of some kind given the lack of response/activity?

Comment: Hi chadhoc, sorry for slow response. Unfortunately we've not been able to resolve this issue other than to eliminate concurrent threads in our system. This means there's only ever one instance of the proc running and this stops the deadlocks from occuring. We set the isolation level to 2 or 3 and this initally seemed to make a difference but we think this was more a lull in activity than a fix as before we knew it deadlocks were back. It seems to be hardware related - if the insert was quicker then the s lock would go to IX quicker and thus the chance of getting a deadlock would be lower...?

Answer (score 3):

First off, if you can post the procedure code, table schema, and index structure it would be very helpful in determining what is going on specifically.

Next thing to note is that you are using [serializable transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx), the most restrictive form of pessimistic locking (the session's isolation level is seen in the deadlock graph output process info list). Chances are, you don't need this - if you are using the .NET TransactionScope library, I believe they use Serializable by default and you'll want to explicitly specify the [appropriate Isolation Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213034(SQL.80).aspx). If you do need the semantics of a serializable transaction for some reason, take a look at [Snapshot Isolation instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(VS.80).aspx), which is an optimistic form of concurrency which supports the serialized semantics. This is almost certainly playing a part in your deadlock issue here, which I explain further below.

As for the deadlock in your case - you mention in your question that to avoid deadlocks you explicitly select with an xlock,rowlock from the [cmsreceiptarchive] table in the procedure before the insert to [cmsreceipt] which fires a trigger to update the [cmsreceiptarchive] table (I'm not going to get in to whether or not this is the correct approach here because we can't see the code or the scenario, but this would most likely be unnecessary). Back to the problem at hand - in this case you aren't getting a deadlock on the [cmsreceiptarchive] table/indexes, you are getting a deadlock on the [cmsreceipts] table itself at the point of the insert, so the fact that you are performing the select against the [cmsreceiptarchive] actually has nothing to do with this particular deadlock. Interpreting the deadlock graph to a more simplistic approach:

```
SPID 57 is running (line 43 of procedure XXX.dbo.Main_InsertCmsReceipt):
    insert into CmsReceipt with (updlock) ( CmsReceiptId, ModifiedAt, ModifiedBy, CmsMessageId, Status, Details, ReceiptTimestamp, SenderName, SenderId ) 
    values ( @New_CmsReceiptId, @New_ModifiedAt, @New_ModifiedBy, @New_CmsMessageId, @New_Status, @New_Details, @New_ReceiptTimestamp, @New_SenderName, @New_SenderId )

    * HOLDS a Shared lock on dbo.CmsReceipt

    * WAITING for an IX lock (convert from the S lock) on dbo.CmsReceipt
        (SPID 69 holds a conflicting Shared Object)

SPID 69 is running (line 43 of procedure XXX.dbo.Main_InsertCmsReceipt):
    insert into CmsReceipt with (updlock) ( CmsReceiptId, ModifiedAt, ModifiedBy, CmsMessageId, Status, Details, ReceiptTimestamp, SenderName, SenderId ) 
    values ( @New_CmsReceiptId, @New_ModifiedAt, @New_ModifiedBy, @New_CmsMessageId, @New_Status, @New_Details, @New_ReceiptTimestamp, @New_SenderName, @New_SenderId )

    * HOLDS a Shared lock on dbo.CmsReceipt

    * WAITING for an IX lock (convert from the S lock) on dbo.CmsReceipt
        (SPID 57 holds a conflicting Shared Object)
```

As you can see, there is no mention of the [cmsreceiptarchive] table. You have 2 spids that each hold an object-level Shared lock on the [cmsreceipt] table - this is most likely (can't tell for sure without the code) due to the combination of 2 things:

1. You are using a serializable isolation model, which will hold shared locks for the duration of the transaction (as opposed to the duration of a particular statement within a transaction as would be the case in a read-committed type isolation mode)
2. You are doing something earlier in the procedure/code to require a table-level shared lock (likely a table scan, or large block scan touching enough rows to escalate to the table-level lock vs. a range lock as you'd typically see in a serializable transaction).

Unless we can see the code in the procedure and possibly the table schema including indexes, this is probably the best guess/info I can give you. If you can post the procedure code, table schema, and index structure, should be able to easily determine what is going on specifically.

As for interpreting your deadlock output, Bart Duncan has a [3-part series on deciphering deadlock output](http://blogs.msdn.com/bartd/archive/tags/SQL+Deadlocks/default.aspx) which is a highly recommended read (and is what I used here and typically always) to help understand/decipher what is going on. You can also see an overview of [concurrency, isolation models and the effect on standard DML operations along with demo scripts in here](http://blogs.msdn.com/chadboyd/archive/2007/05/29/so-you-think-you-know-sql-concurrency-and-locking.aspx).

---

### EDIT: Adding response to new questions posed in an answer

Ok, couple of things we need to set straight from your new question:

1. DBCC USEROPTIONS isn't a database level context, it's a session (i.e. spid, connection) level context - what you see returned from this is specific to the session it is run in (in this case, your connection in SSMS or whatever you are running it from. READ COMMITTED is most likely the default isolation level (unless that's been changed), however the spids involved in your deadlock scenario ARE using the SERIALIZABLE isolation model (it's shown in the output above).
2. You are mis-interpreting what SQL_Menace is saying in the link you posted - he is saying that the code inside the procedure will run at the serializable isolation model for inline code in a session outside the procedure execution *because it is explicitly set to that level within the procedure*, not because it is that way by default. To try and better explain, here is the exact example he used with some additional commentary to help understand

Code sample taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/54dafdab-fb18-4d47-b607-e4c661726574), added some commentary:

```
use tempdb;
go

-- Create a test procedure to demonstrate with
create proc usp_test
as
-- Set the isolation level to read uncommitted - this will be the level used
-- for the duration of the procedure execution and any code within this procedure
-- unless explicitly set otherwise via another set statement or query hints
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;

-- This will show you that the isolation level is 1, which is equivalent
-- to read uncommitted
select  transaction_isolation_level, session_id 
from    sys.dm_exec_sessions
where   session_id = @@spid;
go


-- Now, run some code (what SQL_Menace is referring to as *inline* code)


-- Check the current isolation level, should be the default, which is 
-- by default READ COMMITTED (equivalent to 2)
select  transaction_isolation_level, session_id 
from    sys.dm_exec_sessions
where   session_id = @@spid;

-- Explicitly set the isolation level to something else, serializable. This
-- will set the isolation method to serializable for this session and any
-- code executed in this context, unless explicitly set to something else
set transaction isolation level serializable;

-- Take another look at the isolation level - now will be 4, serializable
select  transaction_isolation_level, session_id 
from    sys.dm_exec_sessions
where   session_id = @@spid;

-- Execute the stored procedure - note that within the stored procedure's
-- context, the isolation level is running at 1 (read uncommitted)
exec usp_test;

-- Check the isolation level in this session/context again - note that it
-- is again running under the serializable isolation level, since the
-- read uncommitted level only applies for the duration of the procedure
-- code context
select  transaction_isolation_level, session_id 
from    sys.dm_exec_sessions
where   session_id = @@spid;

-- Repeat the same tests using a different isolation level - it isn't
-- always serializable, it is whatever the session is set to, which can
-- be the default or whatever you explicitly set it to
set transaction isolation level repeatable read;

-- Now it is 3 (repeatable read)...
select  transaction_isolation_level, session_id 
from    sys.dm_exec_sessions
where   session_id = @@spid;

-- Still going to be 1 within the procedure
exec usp_test;

-- Back to 3 again (repeatable read)
select  transaction_isolation_level, session_id 
from    sys.dm_exec_sessions
where   session_id = @@spid;

go


-- Cleanup
drop procedure usp_test;
go
```

Ok, now back to the deadlock situation. As I mentioned above, *your deadlock is occurring on the [CmsReceipt] table, not the [CmsMessageUnarchived] table, so the dummy select you are doing prior to the insert into the [CmsReceipt] table has nothing to do with the deadlock (or most likely does not)* - the deadlock is on the CmsReceipt table, not the Unarchived table.

Can you also post the code that is included in the trigger so we can see what you are doing within the trigger that might be affecting things (i.e. is it an instead-of trigger vs. an for/after trigger)? Additionally, is there any code run within the same session prior to the execution of the stored procedure in question?

Comment: Hi chadhoc, answered your post above as there wasn't enough room to post everything in a comment. Thanks again.